# 'Unfinished Business' hasn't unlocked despite finishing two separate challenges

Tags: achievements, tomb-raider-2013

The description given in order to complete this trophy is to finish one challenge.

I have finished two - Illumination and the egg one, however the trophy has not popped up. Is this a glitch?

I'm playing on the PS3.

Comment: I've edited this question to be tagged with the game's title. There's no need to put the title of the game in the title of the question, as it's already in the tag.

Answer (score 1):

This achievement was awarded to me on completion of the Illumination challenge, which was the first I completed. I completed the other challenges later for the 'Inconcievable!' achievement.

One caveat: I played on an Xbox 360.

However, other sites do outline how to get this trophy, with video walkthroughs from PS3 users. (Eg: http://www.tombraidergirl.com/tr9/trophies.php)

Your experience sounds like a glitch.

You could try completing the 'Ghost Hunter' challenge in the coastal forest, as it is technically the first challenge available.